# Problem using dplyr to create a lead window without further packages

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got data like this:

```
ID  Change
1.00    -2
2.00    -4
3.00    3
4.00    -1
5.00    5
6.00    6
7.00    2
8.00    -5
9.00    3
10.00   -5
11.00   2
12.00   6
13.00   1
```

and I'm trying to create a column which measures which comes first, a cumulative change of +5, or -5? The output, is 1 for +5, 0 for -5. So my expected frame would look like this:

```
ID  Change  Out
1.00    -2  1
2.00    -4  1
3.00    3   1
4.00    -1  1
5.00    5   1
6.00    6   0
7.00    2   0
8.00    -5  1
9.00    3   0
10.00   -5  1
11.00   2   1
12.00   6   Na
13.00   1   Na
```

I'm trying this code:

```
myfunc <- function(v){
  v<- cumsum(v)
  up <- which(v >= 5)[1]
  down <- which(v<= -5)[1]
  return(up>down)
}

df %>%
  mutate('out' = myfunc(lead(Change, replace = 0)))
```

but I just get a list of NA values. I found another thread advising to try `ungroup()` but that didn't change anything. I also tried slicing with `[row_number():n()]` which also didn't help.
I'm quite unfamiliar with dplyr so any help is appreciated.

due to work restrictions, I can't use packages like `zoo` to do rolling functions (eg `rollapply`) that way

EDIT: so to clarify, each out 'Out' column finds the cumulative sum of all the 'Change' values from the next row onwards. It then finds the first index where 5 or more occurs, andthe first index -5 or less occurs. If the +5 occurs before -5, then it shows as 1, otherwise its a 0.
So on the first row, -4+3-1+5=+5, 4 steps in, which occurs before -5(which in this case never actually occurs).
The last 2 values are NA because neither a +5 or a -5 occurs from those rows onwards. Hope that clarifies

Comment: I don't really understand the relationship between Change and Out. Can you explain a few rows from the expected frame? Why are the last two values NA?

Comment: Ive just wriiten an edit, which hopefully clarifies

Comment: In the future @DataMonkey it would be better to provide a more easy to access data frame. So instead of the tabulated format you have in your question, something like this would be better: `df <- data.frame(id = 1:13, change = c(-2,-4,3,-1,5,6,2,-5,3,-5,2,6,1))
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will achieve what you want, using base R only.

```
library(dplyr)
    
myfunc <- function(v){
  x <- cumsum(v)
  sapply(seq(x), function(i) {
    y <- x - x[i]
    ifelse(y[abs(y) >= 5 & seq(y) > i][1] > 0, 1, 0)
  })
}

mutate(df, out = myfunc(Change))
#> # A tibble: 13 × 3
#>       ID Change   out
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     -2     1
#>  2     2     -4     1
#>  3     3      3     1
#>  4     4     -1     1
#>  5     5      5     1
#>  6     6      6     0
#>  7     7      2     0
#>  8     8     -5     1
#>  9     9      3     0
#> 10    10     -5     1
#> 11    11      2     1
#> 12    12      6    NA
#> 13    13      1    NA
```